# Buttons not the same size

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

So I can't seem to identify what I'm doing wrong. I created a menu with 4 buttons, namely: Update, Register, Records and Sign out. I placed them together in a class and styled them with CSS. They turned out to be of different lengths, I've tried everything I currently know and understand about CSS and I'm stuck.

Here's the CSS code:

```css
.button2 {
    padding:15px 150px;
    margin:0px auto;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:#221e1f;
    font-family:corbel;
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:  1px solid #d13129;
    background: #d13129;
    width:300px; /* set a width, can be fixed or percentage */
    display:block; /* by default <a> tags arn't block elements and need to be for setting a width */
}
```

picture with the new edit:
http://gyazo.com/7c7203de14e01873b59e60392fa76207

Comment: well you didn't set a width. So unless the text in the buttons is the same length, they will be different lengths.

Comment: What HTML elements are you using for the buttons? Have you set the class on the buttons or the element containing the buttons?

Comment: setting the width doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: if it's an <a> tag then set it to display:block; aswell.

Comment: I don't seem to follow. Can you please elaborate?Thanks,sorry for being a little slow, just woke up.

Comment: @Mandirigma I just edited your post, check out the last two properties.

Comment: Yeah, I saw what you did. It solved the size problem but then it destroyed the formatting. I'll post a picture.

Comment: it's setting them to 300px width as per my example, but you can set that to whatever you need it to be. also if you want the text centered just use text-align:center; instead of padding on the side. The padding on the sides will add to the overall width. Hope you get it going!

Answer (score 0):

You should define Height and Width in the css as well. Something like:

```
  height:5px;
  width:15px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a width in the CSS (e.g. 'width: 50px;'). Unless you do this the size will match however large the text within the button is (plus the padding/borders).

Comment: Tried doing that, it didn't do anything.

Comment: If this is for a menu/nav bar try giving the anchor the width attribute. So if the button has a class called 'button1' try: .button1 a {width: 50px;}

Comment: I wish I could post a picture here to show what I mean exactly. I don't know if it's allowed though. already did that. Should I assign different classes for each of the buttons?

Comment: No, as long as they all have the same class then all you need to do is reference that one class within the CSS and it will apply to everything within the HTML that has that class attribute. Can you edit your original post and maybe show some more of the code?